# batch to run java, can't find class

Tags: java, cmd

I am writing a batch file to compile and run java. Below is the code. I can compile it. The problem is, it can run the java class. it will give me the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/Sender
```

here is the code

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
set SOURCE=./src
set LIB=./lib
set BIN=./bin

set CLASSPATH=%LIB%/*

set CURRENTDIR=%CD%
echo %CURRENTDIR%

"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\javac -d %BIN% -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" "%SOURCE%/com/Sender.java" 
"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%:%BIN%" com.Sender %CURRENTDIR%
pause
```

Comment: Once it comes to two commands, I turn to Ant or an IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the classpath elements by `;` (semicolon), not by `:` (colon) on Windows. Colon is used on *nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

Your CLASSPATH is not correct. The resulting class com/Sender.class is not referable from the path you mentioned. A better way is to generate all the class files, pack them into a jar and mention them in your classpath.